# Azure build pipeline - published zip file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am fairly new to Azure Build pipelines, but I am having issues finding the answer to this.

When I build my artifact, the results include my server code files (vb and cs). How do I construct a build pipeline where the artifacts that are dropped are only the files I need to publish a site? Meaning, I want to exclude vb and cs files, but include necessary dll's and html/java script files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're publishing the wrong thing as an artifact. You're probably specifying `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` or `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` as the root folder for your artifacts.

Look at your build step. Are you specifying an output directory as an MSBuild argument? If not, specify one. Specifically, `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. So you'd pass the MSBuild argument `/p:OutDir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

Then publish `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` instead of whatever folder you're currently publishing.

Comment: My current MSBuild arguments are - /p:WebPublishMethod=Package  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:DeployOnBuild=true. When I add /p:OutputDir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) I get an error that it can't find my application config file in the bin folder.

Comment: Have you checked the server?  From what, I would guess that $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) should only contain the zip for your site (you can ignore the output dir if it's erroring, you should be good to go with what you have).